# Wait for user confirmation before triggering event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to figure out how events works and how to wait for a second event to trigger before the original event is being executed.

```
 $.fn.customConfirm = function (message){
     // Create modal
     // then ...
     $(confirmModal).find("modal-footer a").click(function(e2){
          e2.preventDefault();
          return ($(this).hasClass("dialogConfirm")); // Returns true if option has class dialogConfirm
     });
 };

 $("a[data-confirm]", click(function(e){
      if (!$.customConfirm($(this).attr("data-confirm")))
          return false; // Only if customConfirm returns false
      // Continue
 });
```

This works like a charm. `customConfirm` creates a bootstrap modal with 2 buttons (confirm/cancel) and sets the `data-confirm` attribute value as the modal-body html.

What I don't know how to solve is how to handle the event `e` based on the user interaction with the modal. As of now it just shows the modal dialog and the original event seems to do nothing.

Comment: You have to set something up such that the confirmation dialog itself knows to trigger some action. You can't set it up with a simple `if` test like you've got because it's all asynchronous.

Comment: @Pointy So custom dialogs cannot act as the JS `confirm()` event?

Comment: No, you can't make the browser do that other than through the built-in `confirm()`.  You can however pass a callback function into your confirm dialog, and have that code call it upon the button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the attribute `data-confirmed` to the clicked element if the user confirms and then triggering a second `click()` on the original element.

```
$.fn.customConfirm = function (message){
      var handle = $(this);
      // Create modal
      // then ...
      $(confirmModal).find("modal-footer a").click(function(e2){
           e2.preventDefault();
           $(handle).attr("data-confirmed", ($(this).hasClass("dialogConfirm")))[0].click();
           return false;
      });
 };

$("a[data-confirm]").click(function(e){
     if ($(this).attr("data-confirmed") !== "true")
     {
           e.preventDefault();
           $(this).customConfirm();
           return false;
     }
     $(this).removeAttr("data-confirmed");

     // Continue
});
```